# Overlap Grid with Material ui

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, grid, material-ui

I am trying to overlap two grid Items with Material UI, But I have failed after trying different approaches,if someone can point me to the right direction.

so basically trying to center **item 2** and get **item 1** *about **1/3** into **item 2**.*

```
  <Grid
    container
    direction="column"
    justify="flex-start"
    alignItems="flex-start"
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "pink" }}
  >
    <Grid
      item
      container
      xs={4}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "blue" }}
    >
      1
    </Grid>

    <Grid
      item
      xs={6}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "red" }}
    >
      <Grid
        item
        xs={2}
        justify="center"
        style={{ width: "10", background: "grey" }}
      >
        <h1>2/2</h1>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid
      item
      xs={4}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", background: "brown" }}
    >
      3
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want to be using a grid for this. Grid items by definition are laid out in a grid, not overlapping.

Comment: Hi JMadelaine! Oh I am newbie and I figured that grid is a quick solution. please let me know what approach do you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: If you're new to React and development in general, I would not use third party libraries like material UI, and start building your own components. You will understand what is going on much easier that way.

Comment: I fear that JMadelaine may have overstated the case a bit. If a solution can be found in material-ui, then I think offering that solution is FAR preferable to sending a self-described newbie off into the wilderness of React, JSX, and styling.

Answer (score -1):

First your second grid is wrong it can't be a `container` and an `item` at the same time.

Second you should check this [Grid system](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive) and this [Breakpoint system](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#breakpoints)that would let you understand the props you have to pass to you grid (parent and childrens) for have the wanted layout.

Basically you where trying to to this:

```
<Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
    <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12} sm={12}>
        <Typography>Item 2</Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={4} md={4} lg={4} xl={4} sm={}>
            <Typography>Item 1</Typography>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hope that have help you !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm pretty sure you're incorrect. I encourage you to scroll down the "Grid system" link you provided and look at "Nested Grid". Nested grid behavior is frequently required. The `component` prop allows the item to contain other items.

Answer (score -1):

Grid items can also be containers. Be careful of the order though. Use <Grid container item ...

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).